# Swift : Dismiss a PopOver when a tableview cell is selected

Tags: swift, popover, dismiss

I have a two controllers. The first one has a navigation bar with an item of Bookmarks Button which I press to display my second controller with has a tableview inside of it.

[Example project from this link : http://www.koraybirand.co.uk/download/xcode/PopTest.zip](http://www.koraybirand.co.uk/download.asp?usr=pop&file=/download/xcode/PopTest.zip)

I want to be able to select one cell and then dismiss the popover view.
[image: The layout is as seems]

One other strange behaviour is that first cell displays an alert viewcontroller which works fine on an iPhone but on an iPad the popover is suddenly resize to alerviewcontroller's size.

[image]

here is my main view controller :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "popoverSegue" {

        let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}


}
```

and here is my popover:

```
class menuViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var links : [String] = ["Share", "Manage"]
var currentPopover:UIPopoverController!

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return links.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "No Bookmarks to Share", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = links[indexPath.row] as String
    return cell
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}



}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

in menuViewController is enough to dismiss popover. So code will look like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "No Bookmarks to Share", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to dismiss it before the alert controller is displayed not when the cancel button is clicked

Comment: Allright, then just put self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) outside of the cancelAction's block. I've edited my answer like that.

Comment: @KorayBirand did you find way to bring back data selected to main view controller?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but instead of the alert, with a ViewController. The problem is when I press an item, the viewController is presented and then disappears, but the popover is still visible /: Someone help me?